# Merge four A6 pages into one page A4

Tags: linux, pdf, pdftk

Hello i've got problem with merge 4 pages A6 into one page A4.

I was trying with ghostscript, pdftk and others... closest was pdftk command:

```
pdfnup --nup 2x2 --paper a4paper --noautoscale true --outfile a4.pdf a6.pdf
```

But got this error...

```
pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.
pdfjam: Reading any site-wide or user-specific defaults...
      (none found)
pdfjam ERROR: can't find pdflatex!
```

I've got TeX installed but error still occults.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your distribution is Ubuntu. (for other distributions the solution should be similar)

1. Be sure you have installed `texlive-latex-extra` package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive-latex-extra).
   There was an official [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/+bug/1085666) on similar issue and has been fixed.
2. Check if you have `pdflatex` executable on your system. Be sure that the location is listed in `$PATH`. If not add it into it.